# Is it possible to use EinsumDense instead of multiple parallel Dense layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have an input of shape `(None, 20, 250)`, where 20 is my context window and 250 my embedding dimension.

I want to apply a **different** dense 250 -> 250 for each element in the context window.
The following code works and does what I want, but does not use Einsum:

```
x = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
x = [layers.Dense(250)(i) for i in x]
x = tf.stack(x, axis=1)
```

If I understand Einsum correctly, the following code should do the exact same:

```
einsum = EinsumDense('abc,cbd->abd', output_shape=[20, 250], bias_axes='bd')
x = einsum(x)
```

The documentation for EinsumDense states that `ab,bc->ac` would be equivalent to a dense layer, so I figured this should work.
However I'm getting drastically different results when doing this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!!

```
einsum = EinsumDense('abc,cd->abd', output_shape=[20, 250], bias_axes='d')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30225403)

Comment: No, this is just a shared dense

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just using a different initialization of the parameters to test stuff. Your code seems to work just fine if we initialize the weights consistently and call the layer with the same input. Here I initialize all weights with ones and check that the output is consistent between the two approaches:

```
inp = tensorflow.random.normal(shape=[17, 20, 50])

x = tf.unstack(inp, axis=1)
x = [layers.Dense(250, kernel_initializer='ones')(i) for i in x]
x = tf.stack(x, axis=1)
x = x.numpy()

einsum = core.EinsumDense('abc,cbd->abd', output_shape=[20, 250], bias_axes='bd', kernel_initializer='ones')
y = einsum(inp)
y = y.numpy()

print(np.sum(x==y), len(x.flatten()))
```

Output:

```
85000 85000
```

With the default glorot initializer you have a stochastic initialization and probably this is the reason why you were having incompatibility between the two approaches.

(NB: test done with tensorflow version 2.15.0)